# Occasionally, I get the error: code -32000, message: header not found. When working with smart contracts with web3 in nodejs

Tags: web3js, bsc

I've tried to fix this for a whole day now. I've read the answers to the question: [What is that error called "code: -32000, message: 'header not found'" when I deploy smart contracts to BSC?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/112991/what-is-that-error-called-code-32000-message-header-not-found-when-i-dep)
and many more similar questions. But no answers I've come across have fixed my problem.

I've gone crazy with try catch statements and promise catching for all web3 smart contract calls without any success.

Code sample for DODO DEX:

```js
try {
  this.web3 = new Web3(new HDWalletProvider(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, 
      process.env.RPC_URL));
}catch(err) {
  console.log("base this.web3 error", err)
}

this.pool = new this.web3.eth.Contract(POOL_ABI, this.poolAddress);

this.pairs = ['0x0fe261aee0d1c4dfddee4102e82dd425999065f4'];

this.directions = 0;

const baseResult = await this.pool.methods.querySellBase(process.env.WALLET, this.tradingAmount).call()

let minReturnAmount = this.#calculateMinReturnAmount(baseResult.receiveQuoteAmount);
let deadline = this.#calculateDeadline();

const gas = await this.proxy.methods.dodoSwapV2TokenToToken(
  this.fromToken, //WBNB's contract address
  this.toToken, //BUSD's contract address
  this.tradingAmount,
  minReturnAmount,
  this.pairs,
  this.directions,
  false,
  deadline
).estimateGas()
```

process.env.RPC_URL = "https://bsc-dataseed2.binance.org/"
I have tried switching RPC_URL many times without success.

The code above is running in a class. I haven't included all functions as they only perform math equations.

The code does work and only sometimes throws the error:

```bash
uncaughtException: Unhandled error. ({ code: -32000, message: 'header not found' })
Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({ code: -32000, message: 'header not found' })
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at Web3ProviderEngine.emit (node:events:379:17)
    at /home/orbitalskycake/crypto-bot/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:54:14
    at afterRequest (/home/orbitalskycake/crypto-bot/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:148:21)
    at /home/orbitalskycake/crypto-bot/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:174:21
    at /home/orbitalskycake/crypto-bot/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:232:9
    at /home/orbitalskycake/crypto-bot/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12:16
    at replenish (/home/orbitalskycake/crypto-bot/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:61:25)
    at /home/orbitalskycake/crypto-bot/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:71:9
    at eachLimit (/home/orbitalskycake/crypto-bot/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/node_modules/async/eachLimit.js:43:36)
    at /home/orbitalskycake/crypto-bot/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/node_modules/async/internal/doLimit.js:9:16
    at end (/home/orbitalskycake/crypto-bot/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:211:5)
    at Request._callback (/home/orbitalskycake/crypto-bot/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:70:28)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/orbitalskycake/crypto-bot/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/orbitalskycake/crypto-bot/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
```

If anyone needs more code feel free to ask.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but my intuition tells me that the rpc node you are using falls out of sync with the blockchain. You could try with different rpc such as the one offered by moralis (free tier) and not rely on the "official" rpc that may be performing poorly.

Comment: @Undead8 Thank you! Using moralis seems to have solved the error.